# New to JS. I'm trying to code something that toggles divs on a site using .setProperty, but nothing happens

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I'm using the `display` property on my divs and they are manually toggled on/off by the user when they click a button. I have tried this using the `visibility` property and it works, but it leaves a blank space when the div is toggled off, which I don't want.

Here's my current code. It does not return any errors; I feel like the logic I tried to implement is just off, but I can't see it.

```js
function init() {
  let current = 1
  show(current)
}

function show(n) {
  document.getElementById(n).style.setProperty('display', 'block');

  let current = n;
  for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    if (i != current) {
      document.getElementById(i).style.setProperty('display', 'none');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  display: none
}

html {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
  <!-- no real reason to make a 'main' div, but i plan to when i implement this into my site -->
  <div id="main">
    <div id="1">div1</div>
    <div id="2">div2</div>
    <div id="3">div3</div>
    <div id="4">div4</div>
  </div>

  <button onclick="show(1)">show 1</button>
  <button onclick="show(2)">show 2</button>
  <button onclick="show(3)">show 3</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Your "main" `<div>` gets `display: none` from your CSS, so it doesn't matter what you do to the contained blocks, they're also not displayed.

Comment: Your browser DOM inspector tool is a good way to figure out problems like this, because it explains everything about why elements look the way they do (or in this case, look like nothing).

Comment: "*[There's] no real reason to make a 'main' div...*" - this is entirely true, though it's tangential to your problem; rather than using a `<div>`, with a class-name, why not simply use [semantic HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics#semantics_in_html)  such as [`<main>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main), or [`<section>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section)?

Comment: Additionally, you should avoid ids like the plague. At best, you'll end with painful duplicate-id-bugs. At worst, you'll have a tonne of unmaintainable id-based code.

Think of ids as defining all your javascript variables globally. `for(window.i = 0; window.i < window.someCounter; window.i++)` - looks bad right? That's how bad ids are.

Comment: Any reason why you don't give feedback to the people who take time to answer your questions?

Answer (score 0):

Your div with id 'main' is being hidden with the display none property to the div. Update the css as below

```js
function init(){
        show(1)
    }

function show(n) {
        document.getElementById(n).style.display = 'block';
        var el = document.getElementById(n);
        for (let i = 1 ; i <=4 ; i++) {
            if (i != n) {
                document.getElementById(i).style.display = 'none';
            }
        }



    }
```

```css
#main div {
      background: red;
      padding: 10px;
      color: white;
      margin: 10px;
      display:none
  }
  #main div:first-child{
      display:block;
  }
  html {
      background: grey;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <!-- no real reason to make a 'main' div, but i plan to when i implement this into my site -->
<div id="main"> 
    <div id="1">div1</div>
    <div id="2">div2</div>
    <div id="3">div3 </div>
    <div id="4">div4</div>
</div>
<br />
  <button onclick="show(1)">show 1</button>
  <button onclick="show(2)">show 2</button>
  <button onclick="show(3)">show 3</button>
  <button onclick="show(4)">show 3</button>
</body>
```

Comment: there's a flicker showing all divs at the page load. looks amateur

Comment: @Alexander, is there any way you could have commented in a constructive manner? What do you think Akhil could do to mitigate that problem? As written, in English, your comment seems quite mean spirited (though I fully believe that's not intended).

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev The  question is 'Why its not working', and I believe the solution points the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The 'main' element has `display:none;` applied to it as well, so child elements will automatically not display, despite changes you make to them individually.

To fix this, just need to add `#main` in front of `div` in your css, to ensure it effects only child div elements.

A few additional things to mention:

1. I saw you targeted `html` in your css, but that can cause the body to have a white background in certain browsers, so it now targets `body` instead.
2. I got rid of the current variable as it wasn't needed.
3. To save you having to type out `document.getElementById(n).etc.etc` a ton of times, I put it into a function called `setStyleProp(id,propStr,valStr)`
4. Not sure why you want to hide a 4th element, aside from testing? But I left it in as it's your call.

I hope this helps!

```js
function init() {
  show(1);
}
function setStyleProp(id,propStr,valStr){
  document.getElementById(id).style.setProperty(propStr,valStr);
}
function show(n) {
  setStyleProp(n,'display', 'block');
  for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    if (i !== n) {
      setStyleProp(i,'display', 'none');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#main div {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  display: none
}

body {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
  <!-- no real reason to make a 'main' div, but i plan to when i implement this into my site -->
  <div id="main">
    <div id="1">div1</div>
    <div id="2">div2</div>
    <div id="3">div3</div>
    <div id="4">div4</div>
  </div>

  <button onclick="show(1)">show 1</button>
  <button onclick="show(2)">show 2</button>
  <button onclick="show(3)">show 3</button>
</body>
```